# How to start XAMPP in my browser after installing it successfully

Tags: apache2, xampp

I followed this link to install XAMPP on my machine: [XAMMP for Linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#382...). I can't open XAMPP in my browser, but I'm getting the `404 errror` i.e

```
Not Found

The requested URL /xampp/index.php was not found on this server.
Apache/2.2.20 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Can anyone help me to find out the error.

Comment: Btw, you can't access your XAMPP server root at '/xampp/index.php'. You have to type 'localhost' instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this command started xampp but however i couldnot access mysql. it says XAMPP: Starting MySQL... XAMPP: Couldn't start MySQL! Anybody has any idea what to do?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The command for starting the server is:

```
$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```

Source here:

[apache friends - xampp for linux](http://www.apachefriends.org/faq_linux.html)

Comment: its not working.. we tried it.. some other suggestions please

Comment: When you say it's not working, what's the response you get when you try to run this command? Are you sure you've installed XAMPP for Linux the proper way, as instructed here: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html#377 ? Please make sure there is a 'lampp' folder inside your '/opt' directory, and that it contains the script named 'lampp' too.

Comment: its all there in /opt directory.. i m damn sure i installed it.. When i run localhost in my browser i mgetting this message       It works!

This is the default web page for this server.

The web server software is running but no content has been added, yet.

Comment: Ah, I get you now. The problem is you already have a server software running. You need to stop that first in order to be able to run lampp. For commands how to stop Apache, refer to: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-start-restart-stop-apache-web-server/ . Then run 'sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start' and tell me what's the response.

Comment: oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
 * Stopping web server apache2                                                   ... waiting .                                                           [ OK ]
oomsys@oomsysmob-6:~$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
Starting XAMPP for Linux 1.8.1...
XAMPP: Starting Apache with SSL (and PHP5)...
XAMPP: Another MySQL daemon is already running.
XAMPP: XAMPP-ProFTPD is already running.
XAMPP for Linux started. m getting the same like "already running"

Comment: Nice, we're almost there. The response you got told you the following: The old Apache server was stopped; I'm able to start LAMPP; I'm starting LAMPP Apache; I can't start LAMPP MySQL because there's another MySQL server already running. So now you need to stop your existing MySQL server in order to start the LAMPP MySQL server. Run this command: 'sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop', then run 'sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start' again, and let me know the response.

Comment: ya..we have one more doubt

Comment: i cant able to create any folder inside /opt/lampp/htdocs/myphp_project(this is my project name)...

Comment: You need to create it in '/opt/lampp/htdocs/PROJECT_FOLDER/FILE_NAME.php'. When you do, you can access it at the address' http://localhost/PROJECT_FOLDER/FILE_NAME.php'. But if you need any further instructions of this type, I should remind you that AskUbuntu is not the appropriate place for this kind of assistance.

Answer (score 6):

Start command: `$ sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start`

If you want XAMPP to start automatically when you logon to the system:
Open terminal and run following command `sudo gedit /etc/init.d/lampp`

paste following code in open file

```
#!/bin/bash
/opt/lampp/lampp start
```

save and close the file

run following command to make this script executable
`sudo chmod +x /etc/init.d/lampp`

run following command to install init scripts to all runlevel

```
sudo update-rc.d lampp defaults
```

restart the system

Tutorial link with screenshots: [here](http://computernetworkingnotes.com/ubuntu-12-04-tips-and-tricks/how-to-start-xampp-automatically-in-ubuntu.html)

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to launch the XAMPP UI Application with:

```
cd /opt/lampp
```

then

```
sudo ./manager-linux.run # or manager-linux-x64.run
```

You will then see the graphical interface to manage the server where you can check the ports used.

[image: The Resulting Application UI]

Answer (score 0):

This is because, the XAMPP test page is not accessible from the remote clients.
To solve this edit the file /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf.

Note that xampp is installed in /opt/lampp

execute this to edit:

```
sudo nano /opt/lampp/etc/extra/httpd-xampp.conf
```

find the line:

```
require local
```

then comment it by adding a # at the beginning

```
#require local
```

save it

and restart by:

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp restart
```

Now, you’ll be able to access the XAMPP test page.

Answer (score -1):

Click Home Folder in the launcher, then:

File System > opt > lamp > lampp > lampp.lnk

Answer (score -2):

use this command

```
cd /opt/lampp
cd /opt/lampp chmod +x manager-linux-x64.run
cd /opt/lampp ./
```

Comment: -1 These aren't even valid commands. `cd` doesn't take more than a single argument.